# Having Trouble using scanf with char arrays

Tags: c, scanf, arrays

I'm a student learning C, (my previous experience is all python) and am having trouble debugging a program.  The following section in particular has me confused --  I believe I am using scanf or printf incorrectly (and I must use these two, no other functions.)

The intent is to first scan in this string, then pass it into a function do some work on it, but it looks like it is failing at the scan.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main(){
    char hexInput[100];
     printf("enter the hexidecimal to be converted");
     scanf_s("%s",hexInput);
     printf("%s\n",hexInput);
}
```

The above prints null

```
scanf_s("%s",hexInput);
printf("%s\n",hexInput);
```

prints an empty line

```
scanf_s("%s",hexInput);
printf("%s",hexInput);
```

prints nothing.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Generally the input I've been using is a combination of characters and numbers (the project deals with hexadecimal strings), but any string should work with this.  I've been across the web pretty extensively for a solution, I'm sure it's something obvious but I haven't hit on it yet.

I have been using Visual Studio 2008 to compile and debug.

Comment: Not sure what the answer is, but you are using `scanf_s`, but your question states you have to use `scanf`. Also, unless i am missing something, the second code block is the same as the first, but you say it prints differently...

Comment: According to the documentation on [`scanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) you need to pass another argument indicating the length of the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf_s` receives another parameters. The one you're missing is the buffer size. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

So, try something like:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main(){
    char hexInput[100];
    printf("enter the hexidecimal to be converted");
    scanf_s("%s",hexInput, 100);
    printf("%s\n",hexInput);
}
```

Comment: @ArthurChamz The `99` should be `100` or even more properly "... the second argument, which has type type rsize_t and gives the number of elements in the array  ..." C11 §K.3.5.3.2

Comment: @chux Nice one, I didn't know. They think of everything!